# Does azure LUIS support multi-intents in one message

Tags: azure-language-understanding

If I give the message **"open the door and turn on the lights"** come out two intents

1. **"OpenDoor"**
2. **"TurnOnLights"**

does luis support this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer would be "no, you will not be sure of the number of valid intents found".

LUIS is providing a scoring for all the intents of your project when you test a sentence, it is not giving one or two intents. Then it will be what you do with these scorings that will help you to define if there are 1, 2, 3 valid information.

For example if I define a model with 2 intents:

- Turn lights On with an exemple "turn on the lights"
- Open doors with an example "open the door"

Then train and test:

```
{
  "query": "open the door and turn on the lights",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Turn lights On",
    "score": 0.9421587
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Turn lights On",
      "score": 0.9421587
    },
    {
      "intent": "Open doors",
      "score": 0.1412498
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.109745957
    }
  ],
  "entities": [

  ]
}
```

You can be surprised that the "Open doors" scoring is quite bad even if the query contains the utterance.

From my experience with LUIS, you should not try to detect several intents in 1 query.